Arrhenius's 1887 paper
I am writing a review and the mixture law of liquid viscosity was supposedly first proposed by  S Arrhenius in "Arrhenius, Z. physik. Chem., 1, 285 (1887)" as cited in this paper: https://www.nature.com/articles/164799b0
It has not been possible to find the above 1887 paper by Arrhenius. Does anyone have access to it and can share it? Thanks

Visit your local friendly research librarians.

I don't have access to the Nature paper you cited (it's behind a paywall), but I did get a list of references at the bottom of the web page, and clicking on "Google Scholar" for the Arrhenius reference leads to two papers (or at least two different titles). Googling (in Google-Books, date-restricted to 1800s to omit irrelevant mentions of the paper) the titles of the papers (use quotes for a phrase search) took me to this freely available item and to this other freely available item.

What exactly is your problem? I mean, did you actually try to go via the bibliographic details in the reference? Your example is very easy to find indeed if you have access the journal. Or is that your problem?

https://doi.org/10.1515/zpch-1887-0133

And it is available from Sci-Hub under that DOI.
